# Firebase Reset Password Template UI

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication in my web app.
I want to add return to login page link after default reset password success message.

[image: screen shot of success message]

Comment: This is currently not possible in the default email action widget for password reset, though the Firebase Auth team is working on a solution for this.

Comment: Is this still not possible? @Sudheer did you found a solution without having to implement a custom URL? I just want to use the built in implementation but to redirect the user to the login or home page after changing the password

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by passing state via the continue URL. a firebase.auth.ActionCodeSettings needs to be provided.

Check this link for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#configuring_firebase_dynamic_links

Here is an example of resetting an account's password:

```
resetAccountPassword () {
    const actionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'http://example.com/dashboard/?email=' + email,
      handleCodeInApp: false
    }

    // Here you pass the actionCodeSettings Obj (containing the continueURL) as the second argument. 
    firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(() => {
      // Email sent.
      }).catch(e => {
      // An error happened.   
      })
  },
```

This will than show the save button and after clicking it, the user will redirected to the url provided in the actionCodeSettings Obj. Check the image below.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpP9b.png)

I hope this help!

Comment: In this case i need to add a custom reset password button? I'm currently using FirebaseUIAuth and it display a link problems with login, then you can reset, after the user clicks on the email and gets the image in the initial question, but never redirect back to home page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a custom action url in your email then refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

While referring the same, you may require following code changes and functions:

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    initCode();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        initCode();
    }, false);
}

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

function initCode() {
    // Get the action to complete.
    var mode = getParameterByName('mode');
    // Get the one-time code from the query parameter.
    var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode');
    // (Optional) Get the API key from the query parameter.
    var apiKey = getParameterByName('apiKey');
    // (Optional) Get the continue URL from the query parameter if available.
    var continueUrl = getParameterByName('continueUrl');
    // (Optional) Get the language code if available.
    var lang = getParameterByName('lang') || 'en';

    var auth = firebase.auth();

    // Handle the user management action.
    switch (mode) {
        case 'resetPassword':
            // Display reset password handler and UI.
            handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang);
            break;
        case 'recoverEmail':
            // Display email recovery handler and UI.
            handleRecoverEmail(auth, actionCode, lang);
            break;
        case 'verifyEmail':
            // Display email verification handler and UI.
            handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang);
            break;
        default:
            // Error: invalid mode.
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using firebase version 10 with react

```
import { sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../FirebaseConfig";

// your code here .....

    await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email, {
      url: "provide your url here to redirect after password change",
    })

/// your code here......
```